# Attachment Image not displaying on VF page in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, attachment

I'm able to load an image on a Visualforce page using either tag below:

```
<img id="theImage" src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachment.id)}"/>

<apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attachment.id}"/>
```

The same Visualforce page loaded in Salesforce1 is unable to display the image, is it possible to load such an image in SF1 from my Visualforce page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We realized that our photos were not completely uploading, so only 2/3 of the photo was being downloaded to the page. In iOS9 this is not an issue, but in iOS10 the partial photo was not be displayed.

Once we fixed our photo upload to make sure the entire photo was uploading, the photos showed as expected.